# Change where clause for batch delete

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to like to create a batch delete something like:
DELETE t WHERE t.my_attribute = ?

First try was:

```
   private void deleteRecord( ) {
      //loop
      final MyRecord myRecord = new MyRecord();
      myRecord.setMyAttribute(1234);
      getDslContext().batchDelete(myRecord) .execute();
   }
```

But here the SQL contains always the pk instead of my attribute.

Second try was to create a delete statement with a bind value, but here i found no solution how i can create a where clause with ?

```
  //loop
  getDslContext().delete( MY_RECORD ).where( ???)
        .bind( 12234 );
```

Can anybody help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The `DELETE` statement itself

Just add your [comparison predicate](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/comparison-predicate/) as you would in SQL:

```java
getDslContext()
    .delete(T)
    .where(T.MY_ATTRIBUTE.eq(12234))
    .execute();
```

This is assuming you are using the [code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), so you can static import your `com.example.generated.Tables.T` table reference.

#### Batching that

You have two options of batching such statements in jOOQ:

**1. Using the explicit batch API**

[As explained here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/), create a query with a dummy bind value as I've shown above, but don't execute it directly, use the `Batch` API instead:

```java
// Assuming these are your input attributes
List<Integer> attributes = ...

Query query = getDslContext().delete(T).where(T.MY_ATTRIBUTE.eq(0));
getDSLContext()
    .batch(query)
    .bind(attributes
        .stream().map(a -> new Object[] { a }).toArray(Object[][]::new)
    ).execute();
```

**2. Collect individual executions in a batched connection**

You can always use the convenient [batched collection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batched-connection/) in jOOQ to transparently collect executed SQL and delay it into a batch:

```java
getDslContext().batched(c -> {
    for (Integer attribute : attributes)
        c.dsl().getDslContext()
               .delete(T)
               .where(T.MY_ATTRIBUTE.eq(attribute)
               .execute(); // Doesn't execute the query yet
}); // Now the entire batch is executed
```

In the latter case, the SQL string might be re-generated for every single execution, so the former is probably better for simple batches.

#### Bulk execution

However, why batch when you can run a single query? Just do this, perhaps?

```java
getDslContext()
    .delete(T)
    .where(T.MY_ATTRIBUTE.in(attributes))
    .execute();
```

Comment: Yes but then I have no batch deletion, right? I would need a batch deletion

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.

1. That's how I've implemented it. I just wasn't sure if the dummy value was the right way.

2. I'll take a look at that, might help.

3. I don't know enough about JOOQ, but how does JOOQ handle the problem when there are too many parameters in the "IN" clause?
And is the single query with a large "IN" clause > 1000 elements really faster?

Comment: @MelleD: Yes, jOOQ handles both of those problems, see https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-inline-threshold and also https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-in-list-padding/, should you need to worry about cursor cache contention (e.g. in Oracle). Whether it's faster, you have to measure yourself, e.g. using [this benchmark technique](https://www.jooq.org/benchmark). You can also use arrays in some RDBMS: https://blog.jooq.org/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster.

Comment: @MelleD: Keep in mind that one factor which will greatly influence performance is the transaction size. If you're using an MVCC database, deleting 1M records in a single transaction can create tons of concurrency in other sessions accessing this table. There's no silver bullet...

Comment: iam using SQL Server. 
So if I understood the article correctly, shouldn't the BATCH cause fewer problems?

Comment: @MelleD: I can't make a general statement about what approach will be the best for you *in general*.

Comment: ok have to test it. How does JOOQ handle the 2100 parameter issue on SQL Server?

Are the selects then split up, because no more than 2100 parameters go directly inline in one select "IN"

Comment: @MelleD: Have you checked the links I provided? The answer to this is in this one: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-inline-threshold/

Comment: yes of course "By default, jOOQ will automatically inline all bind variables in any SQL statement, once these thresholds have been reached" and what happens then?

As far as I know there is no difference for the SQL Server if you bind 2100 '?' or use 2100 inline values. If you use more than 2100 parameters in an IN you have to do several selects. Or did you have a different experience with it?

Comment: @MelleD: Our integration tests suggest otherwise, but why don't you just try it with jOOQ and see what happens. You can turn on debug logging to see what SQL jOOQ generates: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/

Comment: Ah i found the issue. I thought it's automatically set from the dialect.
Thanks good hint then we have not handle this by us :)

Comment: @MelleD: Yeah, this is part of jOOQ's philosophy. You shouldn't have to handle all those boring, low level details of various SQL dialects. :)

Comment: Very good philosophy from jOOQ :). The learning curve will continue to rise when we move away from JPA.

I was/am only spoiled by spring boot, that such dialect things are set directly, but just tested works perfectly. Additional learned again that inline goes directly nice to know.

Thanks again Lukas for the very good and detailed answer.

Comment: Spring Boot can only auto configure the jOOQ Open Source Edition, I think? Why do you think the learning curve will rise?

Comment: I still have to test spring boot with the non-open source variant.
That was misleading my learning curve will increase ;)